# FastAPI with integrated websocket client freezes, how should i combine those?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, fastapi

I am currently using FastAPI for a small backend. The REST Api part works without any problems. In the next step I would need to query a websocket API and process it in FastAPI. I would like to filter and forward the incoming data. When I start the application, the websocket client starts running, but the actual FastAPI doesn't work after that.

How can I build a FastAPI which can additionally work as websocket client AND server?

Here is my code:

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers import foo
from services import bar as bar

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(foo.router)

@app.on_event('startup')
async def startup_event():
    await bar.wh_client()



class wh_client:
def __init__(self, ):
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx/",
                                     on_message=self.on_message,
                                     on_error=self.on_error,
                                     on_close=self.on_close)
    self.ws = ws
    self.ws.on_open = self.on_open
    self.ws.run_forever()

def on_message(self, message, stuff):
    print(message)
    return message

def on_error(self, error):
    return error

def on_close(self):
    print("### closed ###")

def run(self, *args):
    global driver
    driver = True
    while driver:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.ws.send('message')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            driver = False
    time.sleep(1)
    self.ws.close()
    print("thread terminating...")

def on_open(self, foo):
    thread.start_new_thread(self.run, ())
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have been facing exact same problem. I'm trying to develop a bridge between WS endpoints with asyncio.

Comment: Unfortunately not really. My solution was to split the API into "micro services". Not the best solution and of course with some overhead, but I couldn't solve it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and haven't found a solution online. The solution I came up with looks stupid but works.

```
import asyncio
# websocket endpoint / RX thread
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    ws_tx_thread = Thread(target=websocket_tx_task_wrapper, args = (websocket, to_ws_queue,))
    ws_tx_thread.start()

    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        print(f"WS RX: {data}")

# tx task; sends data from queue
async def websocket_tx_task(ws, _q):
    print("Starting WS tx...")
    
    while True:            
        if(_q.empty() == False):
            cmd = _q.get()
            await ws.send_text(f"Msg: {cmd}")

    print("WS tx thread terminated")

def websocket_tx_task_wrapper(ws, _q):
    asyncio.run(websocket_tx_task(ws, _q))
```

RestAPI and WS can normally co-exist.